# Access VBA: select a report

Tags: ms-access, vba

With Access VBA, I want to change the group criteria of a report.

The code I use is the following. Maybe I am using a wrong syntax for the selection of the report because I get the error `Can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression`.

```
[Report Name].GroupLevel(0).ControlSource = "Department"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the expression `[Report Name]`, Access will try to find a control with that name on the form that runs your code. Since for sure you want to refer to a report named `[Report Name]`, you will have to reference the respective object in the `Reports` collection. There are multible ways to do so, but as you already know the name of the report at design time, the most efficient way is:

```
Reports![Report Name].GroupLevel(0).ControlSource = "Department"
```

Make sure that your report is open when the code runs, and make sure that it is opened in design view if you want the changed report to be saved.